# Windows that pop up appear behind active window?

Tags: firefox, window

I am using Firefox and when I finish downloading a file, I click on the folder icon beside its name. The problem is, the windows appear behind Firefox. It's not isolated to the viewing the destination folder though. Since, for example, Transmission (torrent client) is running on the top tray, when I click on it then `Show Transmission`, the window opens behind Firefox also.

I want to know how to fix this?

Comment: 2023 and this is still happening. Compiz is history, so your solution won't help. First google result, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution. Basically, you need to install CompizConfig Settings Manager. Then go to `General > General Options > Focus & Raise Behaviour` and set `Focus Prevention Level` from `Low` to `Off`.

[image]

Comment: This problem has been bugging me for ages. I noticed it from nautilus and calculator opening up behind open applicatons when launched from keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: cannot agree more.  saved my day.